# Is it possible to exclude some cells from the ipython notebook when using NBConvert

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a method to exclude some cells from the NBconvert process

For instance. An embedded video is cool when running to HTML, but when converting the HTML to PDF it creates a problem. So I want to exclude it in some instances.

Comment: why not save a version of your notebook with that removed and then convert that?

Comment: Hi, yes that is an option. but the environment and building is quite automated so this would be nice. IN Ipython 1.00 there is cell markkup available - you can set slide etc. maybe later on it can be build into that

Answer (score 2):

Found a nice workaround for this, using the 'slides' option of nbconvert:

1. In your iPython notebook under "Cell Toolbar" select "Slideshow"
2. Then in the top right of the cells that you don't want to show select Slide Type "skip"
3. Now run `python nbconvert your_notebook.ipynb --to slides`
4. Instead of serving the slide, just open the resulting html in a browser.

And.. It doesn't contain the slides you told it to skip!

Hope this helps.